# How to get the datetime and timezone from XML DataSet?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an XSD, an XML and I read these two in a dataset

XSD:

```
<xs:schema id="dataset" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ... >
  ...
    <xs:element name="DEEDDATE" type="xs:dateTime" ... />
  ...
```

XML:

```
....
  <DEEDDATE>2014-03-07T00:00:00+02:00</DEEDDATE>
....
```

VB.NET code:

```
xml.ReadXmlSchema(schemafname)
xml.ReadXml(_filename)
```

When I check out the value, I see that it is read as DateTime instead of DateTimeOffset, but still it is converted to my local time, which is not even the same time as the one in the file.

I understand that there is no DateTimeOffset in the xs namespace schema, but ReadXML obviously also reads the timezone, it calculates my localtime and then saves that time as a datetime and discards the timezone.

What can I do to also get the timezone?

Comment: You can't unless you manually parse the xml.  DateTime is stored in computer as UTC.  When time is read/write the local time zone setting is used as default when converting time from/to string.  In this case the date included a timezone so the time was converted to UTC.  So you can only get the timezone of your computer and not the time zone of the date entered since the value was converted to UTC.

Comment: that's not the answer I was looking for, and I still hope there might be a different solution. I find it ridiculous that the ReadXML function is able to read the timezone in the xml, it uses that timezone to convert the time to UTC and then it discards this information without giving me any option to keep it. If it couldn't read the timezone or it would have given an error because of the timezone being there, I would have accepted it as being missing functionality, but in the current state I see it as a bug. I suppose I have a bug to submit now. Anyway, thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Why do you care what the timezone is?  As long as the DateTime is correct it shouldn't matter.  It doesn't matter if is  1:00 PM UTC, 9:00AM Eastern Daylight Time, or 8:00AM CDT they are exactly the same time.

Comment: these xml files have the dates and times when some papers were signed. My program will be run in a different timezone, but the stored time wil be indeed the representation of the same moment in time. Afterwards I will also have to display these dates in the local time of where the papers where signed. I have no knowledge about the location of where these have been signed, so without preserving the original timezone, I will be able to say precisely when in time the papers where signed, but not what was the local time at the location.

Comment: Probably the user interested in this information has some personal knowledge of the local time, because it has personal knowledge of what the document is about, so he could convert the UTC time himself, but a software is supposed to help you, not ask you to convert from UTC to the local time of the signature manually, so it's on me to find a solution.

Comment: Lewis Carroll said 170 years ago "Its all Relative",Time is relative and needs to be synchronized to one timezone to be meaningful.Using Timezone to determine where an event occurred is not a good solution.  If you want to know where then don't use when (this sounds like a line from the Jabberwocky).Include the location in your input data.Databases operating globally uses one timezone for all data entered plus the location of where the data was collected. He took his vorpal sword in hand; Long time the manxome foe he sought— 
So rested he by the Tumtum tree And stood awhile in thought.